# Codeigniter - Email not received

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm using godaddy and host 3 domain on it.I want to send the mail but it's not received into my inbox.

```
$from_email = "admin@inwbg.com";
        $to_email = $post['to'];
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );
        //Load email library
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->from($from_email, 'Reset Password');
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject('INWBG.COM');
        $this->email->message($post['message']);
        if($this->email->send()){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
```

Although i'm received email from my other domain with the same above code.Can anyone help me in this regard ?
I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: It's not going to else part ,

Comment: It's print the the if part 
means that it's return 1